# How to replace part of string with python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a problem replacing a part of the string in Pandas.

I have a list of links of a website like this (for example):

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions
https://stackoverflow.com/some_page
https://stackoverflow.com/about
```

and I would like to replace `https://stackoverflow.com/` with `link/`.

And it should be like this:

```
link/questions
link/some_page
link/about
```

I tried something like this but it replaces the whole string:

```
df.loc[df['links'].str.contains('https://stackoverflow.com/'), 'links'] = 'link/'
```

`links` is the name of column

How do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it always `https://stackoverflow.com/`, or just for this example. If it is static, you can just replace it directly with `str.replace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you what you need as long as the URLs are consistent.

```
data = {
    'Column1' : ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions', 'https://stackoverflow.com/another', 'https://stackoverflow.com/last']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].apply(lambda x : 'Link/' + x.split('/')[-1])
df
```

Comment: in case where the path has more slashes, i.e., additional paths, you can replace x.split('/')[3] with x.split('/')[-1] to pick the last part.

Comment: Your absolutely right! I'll update the code. I like that a lot better makes it more "fault proof" if only a little

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[df['links'].str.contains('https://stackoverflow.com/'), 'links'] = \
    'link/' + df[0].str.extract('.*/(.*)') 

                                     0           links
0  https://stackoverflow.com/questions  link/questions
1  https://stackoverflow.com/some_page  link/some_page
2      https://stackoverflow.com/about      link/about
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `.str.replace` in assignment

```py
df.loc[df['links'].str.contains('https://stackoverflow.com/'), 'links'] = df['links'].str.replace('https://stackoverflow.com/', 'link/')
```

```
print(df)

                             links
0                   link/questions
1                   link/some_page
2                       link/about
3  https://stackoverflow/questions
```